# Running AsyncTasks in sequence and sharing the same layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I'm currently working on a project where I've a `SplashScreen`, which needs to start `AsyncTask#1`, then `AsyncTask#2` to `AsyncTask#5`. Once all that is done, it should bring the user to the `HomeActivity`.

`AsyncTask#1` loads data that is required by all the other tasks. Furthermore, I need `AsyncTask#2` to `AsyncTask#5` to share the same layout (an ImageView + a TextView).

Basically, like a loading screen: `TextView: "Loading items"` and `ImageView: item currently being loaded`. Even though the images will scroll fast, I still have to let the user see the images loading/changing.

I'm writing the following by hand, so ignore syntax errors, if any :/

Currently, my `splashScreen` looks something like this:

```
try {
    DatabaseSetup async1 = new DatabaseSetup(this);
    async1.execute().get;
    new Async2.execute();
    new Async3.execute();
    new Async4.execute();
    new Async5.execute();
} finally {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, HomePage.class);
    StartActivity(i);
}
```

`Async2 to 5`:

```
class Async# extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private TextView tv;
    private ImageView iv;

    public Async#(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        tv = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.tvLoader);
        iv = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.ivLoader);
    }

    doInBackground() {
        publishProgress("Running Async#");
        .
        .
        .
        for(int i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
            publishProgress(item[i].getImageLink());
        }
    }

    onProgress(String... values) {
        if(values[0].contains("Loading")
            tvLoader.setText(values[0]);
        else()
            ivLoader.setImageURL(values[0]);
    }
}
```

So, what would be the right way to do this? I read somewhere that if I use `async1.execute().get()`, the following line will only be called once the Async1 has completed. I'm totally confused. This code works, but I get `Surface#2 is not valid.` sometimes.

I'm not sure if I've to use an inflater? The ImageView is actually a library that I have gotten from Loopj (SmartImageView) to cache the images I get.

LogCat:

```
12-21 16:45:16.722: E/ViewSystem(8941): ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
12-21 16:45:16.772: D/AbsListView(8941): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-21 16:45:16.782: D/AbsListView(8941): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
12-21 16:45:16.782: D/AbsListView(8941): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 16:45:16.782: D/AbsListView(8941): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
12-21 16:45:16.782: D/AbsListView(8941): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 16:45:16.852: D/libEGL(8941): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
12-21 16:45:16.852: D/libEGL(8941): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
12-21 16:45:16.862: D/libEGL(8941): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
12-21 16:45:16.862: I/Adreno200-EGL(8941): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: HAREESHG_Nondeterministic_AU+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_JB_1.9.6_MR2_CL3219408_release_ENGG (CL3219408)
12-21 16:45:16.862: I/Adreno200-EGL(8941): Build Date: 09/28/13 Sat
12-21 16:45:16.862: I/Adreno200-EGL(8941): Local Branch: hhh
12-21 16:45:16.862: I/Adreno200-EGL(8941): Remote Branch: quic/jb_1.9.6_1
12-21 16:45:16.862: I/Adreno200-EGL(8941): Local Patches: 8d50ec23e42ef52b570aa6ff1650afac0b503d78 CL3219408: Fix in the Glreadpixels for negative offsets and larger dimensions.
12-21 16:45:16.862: I/Adreno200-EGL(8941):                  801859126f6ca69482b39a34ca61447e3f7cded8 rb: fix panel settings to clear undrawn/undefined buffers
12-21 16:45:16.862: I/Adreno200-EGL(8941): Reconstruct Branch: LOCAL_PATCH[ES]
12-21 16:45:16.902: D/OpenGLRenderer(8941): Enabling debug mode 0
12-21 16:45:16.932: D/AbsListView(8941): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 16:45:16.952: D/AbsListView(8941): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 16:45:17.022: D/AbsListView(8941): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 16:45:17.052: D/AbsListView(8941): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Thank you very much for reading all this!

Comment: what you mean by Surface#2 is not valid. !!! and if there is an exception raised so please share you logcat

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception. I'll update question with LogCat though

Comment: does you intent (home.class) should start after the finish of the 5th AsyncTask ?

Comment: Yes. I think I should add it to the `onPostExecute` of Async#5?

Comment: yes, because your current code will open the intent just after starting the 5th AsyncTask without waiting for it to be finished

Comment: I will do that, thank you! I din't think of that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simple semaphore-like approach.
Let your Splash activity to implement a simple interface:

```
public interface DecrementCallback{
    public void setCount(int cnt);
    public void onDecrementCount();
}
```

Define a member as counter:

```
private int cnt = 0;
```

Your methods to implement should be something like:

```
        @Override
        public void setCount(int cnt) {
            this.cnt = cnt;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDecrementCount() {
            cnt--;
            if(cnt <= 0){
                /**
                 * Start your main activity
                 */
            }
        }
```

Before starting the asyntasks, set the counter value:

```
setCount(5);
```

Add this method to your asynctasks:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ((DecrementCallback)activity).onDecrementCount();
}
```

You should be very aware of what you do when you share the same TextView and ImageView among all asynctasks, 'cause you can confuse the user if you don't update properly.

**EDIT:**

If you want to run your asynctasks sequentially (first the Async1, then Asyn2, then Async3) you could modify the onPostExecute() method to be something like:

```
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ((DecrementCallback)activity).onDecrementCount();

            if(this instanceof Async1){
            new Async2(activity).execute();
    }else if(this instanceof Async2){
        new Async3(activity).execute();
    }else if(this instanceof Async3){
        new Async4(activity).execute();
    }else if(this instanceof Async4){
        new Async5(activity).execute();
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to start Async1 in your activity.

**EDIT 2:**

If you want to start all the async tasks from the Splash activity, you can modify the callback to something like:

```
public static interface DecrementCallback{
    public void setCount(int cnt);
    public void onDecrementCount(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task);
}
```

The the asynctask method should be:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ((DecrementCallback)activity).onDecrementCount(this);
    }
```

And the overriden method in your activity should look like:

```
@Override
        public void onDecrementCount(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task) {
            cnt--;
            if(cnt <= 0){
                /**
                 * Start your main activity
                 */
            }

            if(task instanceof Async1){
                new Async2(activity).execute();
            }else if(task instanceof Async2){
                new Async3(activity).execute();
            }else if(task instanceof Async3){
                new Async4(activity).execute();
            }else if(task instanceof Async4){
                new Async5(activity).execute();
            }
        }
```

You have a lot of variants exposed. Hope they can be useful.

Regards.

Comment: Well, this would allow me to start the HomePage activity. But how will this allow me to run the AsyncTasks in sequence?

Comment: Do you need to run your asynctasks sequentially or in parallel? The code you posted is for all of them to run in parallel.

Comment: I need them to be run sequentially (says in the title :P).

Comment: Check the edit of the answer to see the way of doing it sequentially.

Comment: That should do the trick :) but is there a way to call them all in SplashScreenActivity? I'll approve your answer :)

Comment: Check the newer edit and don't forget to accept. You've made me think hard my friend :)

Comment: Multithreading is a broad field. I encourage you to keep digging in this area. Regards.